# Azure Elastic Pool Database SQL Connections are Timing Out - DTU Purchasing model

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool

We moved my application to the cloud I've moved a local VM SQL database to Azure SQL Elastic Pool databases 50 DTU. Our database size approximately 4Gb. The problem is that the connection to that new Azure SQL database is so slow and getting command timeout. We use the EF6 database first to handle the SQL stuff.

I have experienced this problem in the last few months. After combing through the logs, the spikes in database traffic that maxed out the DTU limit for my SQL Server.

Aside from increasing DTUs

1. Is there a way to extend the remote command timeout to the azure SQL Elastic Pool database?
2. Is there a way setup fixed DTU usage for each elastic pool database separately?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to extend the remote command timeout to the azure SQL Elastic Pool database?

Command timeout is a client-side setting.  SQL Server doesn't have a server-side command timeout.

But you should troubleshoot your query performance.  To stay as low as 50DTU for the pool you'll need to be very careful of expensive queries.  See eg [Query Performance Insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/query-performance-insight-use)

> Is there a way setup fixed DTU usage for each elastic pool database separately?

You can set min and max per database: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-manage